# SpriteKit, how to import animations from Adobe After Effects

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, after-effects

I'm currently developing a 2d mobile game for ios using SpriteKit as framework.

I made all animations with adobe after effects and now I have to import them into the app.

Instead of using sequence of texture as recommended by Apple and other tutorial, I read that there is an add-on for after effects named Bodymovin. It exports less frame and a .json file.
Then in Xcode I installed a pod named Lottie to make it works.
Well this is ok for UIViewController.

Someone know if there is a working way to export animations from after effects and make it work simply in SpriteKit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its called Lottie animations, where you create your vector animations in After effects and download them as JSONs and import it in the iOS app and start using. But there are some serious restrictions to the method such as text effects won't work..

Have a look at the below - https://lottiefiles.com

There is another similar tool that generates core animation code named as Squall. This is a bit advanced than the Lottie. But this method also has its restrictions.

Here is the link for this tool - http://www.marcuseckert.com/squall/

In present situation, other than these two, you may be out of luck in bringing your animations from adobe after effects to sprite kit in iOS.

Comment: Seems like Lottie is not for games, it has no SpriteKit support, only UIKit views. But it's good.